Integrating the distance (or magnitude) of a vector
I want to integrate $\sin(\theta_0)G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = \frac{\sin(\theta_0)}{4\pi |\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}$ where $|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|$ is the distance between two position vectors.

The magnitude of a vector can be defined as the square root of the dot product of a vector with itself: $|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0| = \sqrt{(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0)\cdot(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0)} = \sqrt{|\textbf{r}|^2 + |\textbf{r}_0|^2 - 2 |\textbf{r}||\textbf{r}_0|\cos(\theta-\theta_0)}$ where to make things simple, we will say that reorienting the $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ of our vectors gives the same exact results and we can then write $\cos(\theta-\theta_0) = \cos(\theta_0)$ for each case. Also, the notation will be $|\textbf{r}| = r$ and $|\textbf{r}_0| = r_0$, the domains will be: $$0 < r \le \infty \land 0 < r_0 \le R  \\ 0\le\theta \le 2\pi \land 0 \le \theta_0 \le 2\pi$$.

With that prefacing out of the way, what I want to do is to perform a polar coordinate double integral with respect to $\theta_0$ and $r_0$:
$$\tag{1} \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r_0\sin(\theta_0)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}d\theta_0 dr_0$$
I tried a similar integral here with $|r-r_0|$ and $|r+r_0|$, and this was solved using piecewise definitions of the magnitudes. What I'd like to know how to perform a similar integral when instead we have $\textbf{vectors}$.
my attempt
From the distance formula:
$$\tag{2}\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r_0\sin(\theta_0)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}d\theta_0 dr_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^R \int_0^{\pi} \frac{r_0\sin(\theta_0)}{\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos(\theta_0)}}d\theta_0 dr_0$$
$s = r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos(\theta_0), ds = +2rr_0\sin(\theta_0)d\theta_0 \rightarrow d\theta_0 =\frac{ds}{2rr_0\sin(\theta_0)}$
$$\tag{3}\frac{1}{4\pi r}\int_0^R \int_{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0}^{r^2+r_0^2+2rr_0} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{s}} dr_0 \\ = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^R \sqrt{s}|_{(r-r_0)^2}^{(r+r_0)^2}dr_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^R \sqrt{(r+r_0)^2}-\sqrt{(r-r_0)^2} dr_0$$
And $\sqrt{(a+b)^2} = |a+b|$
$$ = \tag{4} \frac{1}{2\pi}\Big(\int_0^R |r+r_0| dr_0-\int_0^R |r-r_0|dr_0\Big)$$
And then it would be the exact same process of using piecewise integration as would be done for the magnitude of a function.

Is this right?
Also, notice in (2) that I changed the integral from $\int_0^{2\pi} = 2\int_0^{\pi}$, though I'm not sure if that was legal; however it isn't then (4) would simply evaluate to $0$ which doesn't sound right.
